# Rest API with Magento using PHP with example.

Tags: magento-1.9, api, web-services

I am new to Magento and want to know how to write Rest web services with PHP. Please suggest me with any material or example with full explanation because i gone through many, but couldn't find a good one which is working. I can also say that i don't know how to execute that. please give me a full explanation with example. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good solution using this library PHP.

[Magento Client Library For PHP](https://github.com/cpliakas/magento-client-php)

## **Usage**

**XMLRPC**

The following example returns a list of products with SKUs that start with "123":

```
use Magento\Client\Xmlrpc\MagentoXmlrpcClient;

$client = MagentoXmlrpcClient::factory(array(
    'base_url' => 'http://magentohost',
    'api_user' => 'api.user',
    'api_key'  => 'some.private.key',
));

$filters = array(
    'sku' => array('like' => '123%'),
);

$result = $client->call('catalog_product.list', array($filters));
```

**REST**

The following example returns a list of products:

```
use Magento\Client\Rest\MagentoRestClient;

$client = MagentoRestClient::factory(array(
    'base_url'        => 'http://magentohost',
    'consumer_key'    => 'abc123...',
    'consumer_secret' => 'def456...',
    'token'           => 'ghi789...',
    'token_secret'    => 'jkl012...',
));

$result = $client->get('/api/rest/products')->send()->json();
```

Comment: how can I display my API values as a table format. my post : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/209734/57334

Comment: I am used to WooCommerce and Shopify where we only need a key and secret, how do we get tokens?

Comment: You can use a software called Postman to do the first request just to get these tokens once. After that, you won't need to request again.

Comment: @RafaelCorrêaGomes I just realised I've been watching your YouTube video about authentication. Do you know if I can use the same token forever? My system takes orders every 10 minutes and puts them into a WMS. Can I just use that same token?

Comment: @user2924019 yes, the token can be used forever or until you invalidated it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of REST API in magento2

Step 1: Vendor/Demo/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/get-categorie-id" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\Demo\Api\CategorieInterface" method="getId"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/> 
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Step 2: Vendor/Demo/Api/CategorieInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Demo\Api;

interface CategorieInterface
{
/**
* GET for inquiry api
* @return int
*/
    public function getId();
}
```

Step 3: Vendor/Demo/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Vendor\Demo\Api\CategorieInterface" type="Vendor\Demo\Model\CategorieRepository"/>

</config>
```

Step 4: Vendor/Demo/Model/CategorieRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Demo\Model;

use Vendor\Demo\Api\CategorieInterface;

class CategorieRepository implements CategorieInterface {

    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getId() {
    // Here is your custom logic and return it
        print_r("It's Working");
        die;
    }
}
```

API endpoint like this:

http://demo.com/rest/V1/get-categorie-id

{{BASE_URL}}/rest//{ROUTE_URL}